# Using regex for a URL but it keeps failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL that I am using and trying to validate it with some regex and it keeps failing and I am unsure why that is

```
let a = "https://cdn-myCdn.azure.net/send-to-home4/";
let re = /^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$/;
return re.test(a);
```

I have tried removing the www. but it was still failing

Comment: That worked, can you explain why between the two as an answer incase someone else runs into the same issue please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trouble is with your character classes that do not match a hyphen, `[a-z0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9#]`, while your input contains them. Another major problem is that the `[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+` pattern does not allow more than one single dot in the domain part of the URL, you need to put the `[a-z0-9]+\.` part into a group and set a `+` quantifier to the group. Note that `[a-z0-9]` does not allow uppercase letters, you have them in the URL.

Note also that `www.` matches `www` and any char other than line break char, you need to escape the dot.

So, one possible variation that will work for you is

```
/^(?:(?:https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]+(?:\/[\w#-]+)*\/?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zWuyY/2)

**NOTE**: This is still a very restrictive URL pattern, only use it if you know all the URL you need to validate meet the following:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?` - an optional sequence of `http`, `https`, `ftp`, or `smtp`, followed with `://`
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional sequence of chars, `www.`
- `(?:[\w-]+\.)+`  - 1 or more repetitions of:

  - `[\w-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits or `_`
  - `\.` - a dot
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:\/[\w#-]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[\w#-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits,_`,`#`or`-`
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.